# Formula with incrementing variable based on input array size

Tags: python, function, increment

Say I have a spiral layers where the inner diameter and number of layers were variable. But the number of layers have designations (angles).
Example:

```
ID = 20
Layers = (45, 60, 30)
Layer_thickness = 0.5
```

I want to output an array which contains calculations with each component in 'Layers'. This calculation will use the ID for the first component and for the calculation for each proceeding component would add another layer of thickness

the start of the code with an example formula is:

```
a = []    
    for n, i in Layers:
        a0 = abs((math.pi*ID) / math.tan(math.radians(i)))
        a.append(a0)
```

I cant figure out how to increment the variable ID by the thickness depending on the index of the layer. I know I could easily make another array that looks like (20, 20.5, 21) *but I want to leave flexibility that the input array 'Layer' can have either more or less components in it.*

For this example, could somebody suggest a solution that would follow that last constraint and output the following array (doesn't have to be truncated):

```
a = [37.27, 67.73, 43.66]
```

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to do with `for n, i in Layers`... Did you want to use `enumerate(Layers)`?

Comment: Wait what? Can you review your question and see if it makes sense to you? Please try and rephrase your requirement?

Comment: There will be an input array for the 'Layers'. The number of components in this array is variable depending on the project. The given formula must be calculated for each of the components and output an array of same size. But for each time the calculation is carried out, another layer of thickness must be added to the ID

Comment: @cricket_007 i want to apply the formula to each component in the array individually. Must I use enumerate(Layers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get the index in order to produce `(20, 20.5, 21)`, try

```
ID = 20
Layers = (45, 60, 30)
Layer_thickness = 0.5 

for i, layer in enumerate(Layers):
    value = i*Layer_thickness + ID
    print(value, layer)
```

Otherwise, you're just looking to add onto the ID, like normal

```
for layer in Layers:
    value = ID
    print(value, layer) 
    ID += Layer_thickness
```

Comment: would it be easiest to create a new array within the formula to index which total thickness to use for the diameter? I thought there might be a way to iterate it directly in the formula

Comment: I'm just printing this out to show that's how to get the intermediate value... Feel free to edit the code to do your trigonometry calculations on the angle

Comment: ah i see what you mean. this makes a lot of sense thank you